# JQuery animate a number of divs and write text in it

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I'm struggling at solving a little problem that I posed to myself. I know that on SO are plenty of questions concerning jquerys animation() method, but I do not find any similiar question. In a contrary case, please excuse me.

First of all, how it should work:

I have ten `div`s, which should be animated in their width each individously. After that animation has been concluded, some text should be written in it fading in.

This `div`s got the id userBar1, ..., userBar10. I tried to solve it with the callback method

```
for(var i=0; i<barLengths.length; i++){
    var length = barLengths[i];
    $("#userBar"+(i+1)).animate({width: length+"px"}, function(){
        var t = new Number(usValues[i]).toFixed(2);
        $("#userBar"+(i+1)).html("CHF").fadeIn();
    });
}
```

whereas barLengths is an Array containing the widths the bars should be animated to. This results in no text appending into the `div`s. Same thing when using `text(...)`. 
If I don't put the writing into the `div`s into the callback method, everything works, but the text is already visible at the beginning of the animation.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vj8hy/). As you see, the first ten bars are animated well, but no text is appended. For the others same thing, but the text is appended to early. How can I solve this properly including the fade in of the text? Is it even possible to fade in the text without wrapping it into another `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Vj8hy/2/

Fading in the text can't be a `$.animate` callback inside a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change this bit

```
$(".bar").each(function(i){
$(this).animate({width: lengths[i]+"px"}, function(){
   $("#bar"+(i+1)).html(values[i]);
  console.log("#bar"+(i+1));// same thing with text()
});
```

});

and you should be good. Though the fade **will** require an extra div, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrzRx/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an element, text nodes cannot be animated.

```
(function go(i) {
   $("#bar"+(i+1)).animate({width: lengths[i]+"px"}, function(){
      $('<span>'+values[i]+'</span>').hide().appendTo(this).fadeIn();
      if (i < lengths.length) go(i+1);
   });
})(0)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kkrYR/

Answer (score 1):

The reason your example is not working is that `i` is not in scope in the callback function. You could loop again in that callback function, but the other posters are correct, the fadein effect will need another div.

http://jsfiddle.net/mxDv7/1/